# What happens when I forget to logout in TTY?

Tags: security, tty, console, screen-lock

This is something I have asking myself for some time.
Imagine the following:

- I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to TTY1
- I login there and execute a command
- I switch back to xorg with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>
- I forget that I am still logged in in TTY1

Is this a security issue? I guess so as in my test the normal KDE-Lockscreen (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) doesn't log me out of the TTY.

So is there a solution to automatically log out after X seconds (of inactivity)? Or to maybe logout of all TTY whenever I lock my window manager (KDE in my case)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no integration with DE's lock screen and `tty` logins.

However, you can restrict `bash` sessions by setting the `TMOUT` variable. Edit your `/etc/profile` and set the following content on it:

```
export TMOUT=600 
typeset -r TMOUT
```

Or, to keep things organized, create the file `/etc/profile.d/timeout.sh` with the same content above, and set the executable bit on it ( `chmod +x /etc/profile.d/timeout.sh` ).

This will make all bash sessions older than 600 seconds of inactivity to timeout, and `typeset -r` will set this variable read-only so, users can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `tmux`, you can automatically lock the session using these lines in a `~/.tmux.conf` file:

```
set -g lock-command vlock
set -g lock-after-time 30 # Seconds; 0 = never
```